# Jquery throws an 'Illegal invocation' error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a forum and jquery throws an 'illegal invocation' error.

Here is my jquery code:

```js
$('#formSumbit').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'data-get.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(value) {
          var serialize = $.parseJSON(value);
          if (serialize.success == 'false') {
            $('.alert').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
            $('.alert-msgText').html(serialize.datamsg);
}
}
          });
      });
```

And here is my PHP code:

```html
      <?php
$user = $_POST['user'];
$msg = $_POST['message'];
if(empty($user)&&empty($message)) {
$data = array(
  'success' => 'false',
  'datamsg' => 'Please fill the textboxes'
);
echo json_encode($data);
} else {
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO forums(name,message) VALUES ('$user','$msg')");
$data = array(
'success' => 'true',
'datamsg' => 'Done!'
);
echo json_encode($data);
}
exit();
?>
```

When the textboxes are empty and i click the submit button, nothing seems to work and jquery throws an illegal invocation error. I don't understand what the problem is. Can you please help?
And thanks in advance!

Comment: There are missing brackets and parentheses in your jQuery code. Is that a copy-paste miss or is that the problem? Also, this code is wide open to SQL injection! **Always** use prepared statements: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Sorry it was a copy-paste miss. I messed up!

Comment: Are you sure it's the jquery that's giving the error?  Change the php so that it just returns success or error message (no mysqli_query) and try again.

Comment: Yes i'm sure it's not PHP

Comment: exactly which line is throwing the error? Please show us the full error message text and line number

Comment: P.S. **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: P.P.S. You realise that writing `dataType: 'json'` means that jQuery will automatically try to parse the data coming from the server as JSON, and convert it? Therefore, in your "success" function, `value` will already be parsed and converted to an object. Therefore, `$.parseJSON` should not be needed. You can just access `value.success` directly, for instance. Maybe that's the source of your problem.

Comment: jquery.js:8463 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at add (jquery.js:8463)
    at buildParams (jquery.js:8450)
    at Function.jQuery.param (jquery.js:8483)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.js:9073)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (home:1015)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5183)
    at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4991)

Comment: Lastly, unless you are trying to upload files via this AJAX request, then you could simplify things by replacing `data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,` with just `data: $(this).serialize()`

Comment: No its not working

Comment: same error, or something else?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML of your form please? Then we can try to reproduce the error more easily.

Comment: no now its blank no error no alert nothing

Comment: If there's no error, is it then running the AJAX call? Did you step through the code with your debugger to see what lines are executed? Did you look at the network tool to see if it's made the call to the PHP? if so, what was the response from the server? You seem to be waiting for us to give you a magic solution instead of doing some more detailed debugging...

Comment: $.ajax({
  url:'data-get.php',
  type:'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
  data: $('#formSubmit').serialize(),
  success:function(data) {
  alert(data.datamsg);
  }
});

Comment: No, I asked for the **HTML** of the **form**, not some JavaScript. Thanks.

Comment: <form id="formSubmit" style="margin:10px 10px;">
  <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Enter your name"><br/>
  <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="45" placeholder="Your feedback"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" placeholder="Go">
</form>

Comment: in future please add code to the question, not comments, thanks!

Comment: You have a typo. `<form id="formSubmit"` and `$('#formSumbit')`. The spelling is wrong, so this JS never executes, because it doesn't bind the event to the form. Once you fix that, your code should be fine (with the modifications I suggested, which will get rid of the "illegal" invocation error). Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/khp5rs9m/1/ (I changed your URL for a fake one, just so it would get a response, but you can see where I have altered it and left your settings in the commented-out part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have a typo mismatch between your form and your JavaScript:

`<form id="formSubmit"` and `$('#formSumbit')` - it should be `$('#formSubmit')` to match the spellings.

2) Unless you are trying to upload files via this AJAX request, then you can simplify things by replacing `data: new FormData(this), contentType: false`, with just data: `$(this).serialize()`. This will get rid of the illegal invocation error.

3)  Writing `dataType: 'json'` means that jQuery will automatically try to parse the data coming from the server as JSON, and convert it. Therefore, in your "success" function, `value` will already be parsed and converted to an object. In turn therefore, using `$.parseJSON` is not necessary. You can just access `value.success` directly, for instance.

Here's a fixed version:

```
  $('#formSubmit').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'data-get.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(value) {
        if (value.success == 'false') {
          $('.alert').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
          $('.alert-msgText').html(value.datamsg);
        }       
      }
    });
  });
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/khp5rs9m/2/ (In the demo I changed your URL for a fake one, just so it would get a response, but you can see where I have altered it and left your settings in the commented-out part).